# Oracle: Finding the stored procedure that modifies record on a table

Tags: oracle

I've got a C# code that calls stored procedures and UPDATES a table. Can I monitor each operation made on this table by a SID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this at the database level using Oracle auditing.  See [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php) for good writeup and examples of its use.